# grep for \index{any character except /}

Tags: grep

I would like to grep all substrings like these
\index{abc}
\index{abc def-gh}
but not 
\index{qwe/rty}

i'm trying to run this, but result is not what i need
`grep -rnw -e '\\index{[^/}]+}'`

Would be nice to have some explanation.

Can it be the problem that i run it from git bash under Windows?

Comment: just missing `*`  which tells to match zero or more of preceding character, in your case `[^/}]`.. so, try `grep -rnw -e '\\index{[^/}]*}'`

Comment: @Sundeep thanks, where was plus in original code, i lost somewhere on the way, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: by default, `grep` understands BRE, so either use `grep -rnwE -e '\\index{[^/}]+}'` to use ERE or `grep -rnw -e '\\index{[^/}]\+}'` where BRE understands `\+`

Comment: @Sundeep this gives me all chars till the end of a string

Comment: to extract only matching pattern, add `-o` option

Comment: adding sample input lines and expected output to question would've been better :)

Comment: @Sundeep -o helps:) You may put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
\index{abc} \index{abc def-gh} \index{qwe/rty}

$ grep -rnwo -e '\\index{[^/}]\+}' 
ip.txt:1:\index{abc}
ip.txt:1:\index{abc def-gh}
```

- `-o` print only matching parts

Paraphrasing from `info grep` - search for `Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions`

```
In Basic Regular Expressions the meta-characters ? + { | ( ) lose their special meaning, instead use the backslashed versions \? \+ \{ \| \( \)
```